# unable to get the index of the selected item in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a drop down with values which I am using a drop box to display the items. I want to handle the click event and print the index of the element in the array. The view code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.5.0" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="item" ng-change="handleClick($index)">
  </select>

</html>
```

On the controller I have the function but I am not getting the index on selecting.

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).

controller("myController", function($scope){
     $scope.handleClick = function(index){
     console.log("came inside the handleClick function with the currext index "+index);
    }
    $scope.items=["pradeep","praveen", "sagar","vinod"];
})
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. link to Plunkr - [Link to Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qy4DyJpXKIOKgcMHDzLy?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

`$index` isn't defined when using `ngOptions` - your best bet is to use `indexOf` and find the index:

```
<select ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="handleClick(selectedItem)">
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.handleClick = function(selectedItem) {
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(selectedItem);
}
```